# How can I fix charset encoding when I use RequestDispatcher include a html file?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, dispatcher

I have a login and register dynamic web project using JSP and Servlet.

register.htm aready has:
`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Register Servlet has:

```
    `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`
    `response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");`
    `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`
```

When user submit (in register.html), if it has some errors, Register Servlet do:

`RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/register.html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<font color=red>" + errorsMsg + "</font>");
            rd.include(request, response);`
Then, browser display content which is not UTF8. (Like **Ä�á»ƒ Ä‘Äƒng kÃ½ tÃ i khoáº£n, báº¡n cáº§n Ä‘á»“ng Ã½ vá»›i**
How can I fix it?

Comment: Where does this string come from? Hardcoded in code or DB?

Comment: It comes from register.html.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all HTTP headers before you start writing to the output stream or writer of the response.

And when you start writing to the writer, you have to first write the `<HTML>` and `<HEAD>` tags but in your example you write `<font>`:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<font color=red>" + errorsMsg + "</font>");
```

When you call `rd.include(request, response);` you've already written something to the output which is not what you want.

Comment: errorsMsg displays perfectly, but text come from register.html is bad

Comment: @storky check the encoding of your source files, too

Comment: @cy3er it is UTF8 encoding!

Comment: Check the source code of the page you get in your browser. If it starts with your `<font>` then it is bad. You can't write to the writer and then include a complete HTML page. Then the encoding of the HTML page will probably be omitted.

Comment: @icza I think that it dosen't relate to "out.println("<font color=red>" + errorsMsg + "</font>");". I want to fix encoding of text from register.html which displays bad in browser

Comment: That's what I'm telling, since you include a complete HTML page _in the middle_ of another HTML page, that is bad and the encoding of the individual HTML page might be omitted hence resulting in bad character display.